# I can't use original node.js util module in vue projet

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, module

I've just created a vue projet with vue cli 3 with this command :

```
vue create hello-world
```

Now, I would like to use the util module of Node.js ([this one](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_types_ispromise_value)), but when I use the code below, vue.js load his own module. I would like to load the original node.js util module.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
const originalNodeUtil = require('util');

const regEx = /test/;

if( originalNodeUtil.types.isRegExp(regEx))
    console.log('Success');

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

I begin with vue.js :-(

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue.js runs in the browser, not Node.js. You can't use modules that are built into Node.js.

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can use [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) if you really need any Node module.

Comment: @BeniaminH — No. browserify will not let you use *any* Node module. Read your own link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify#compatibility

Comment: [Here](http://browserify.org/) I can read: _Get browser versions of the node core libraries_ like `util`. In the link you sent they only say that I will "get a browser-specific shim" - it doesn't mean I can't use it.

Comment: @BeniaminH — Some modules can be browserifyed. Some modules can be shimmed (in which case you get a different module). Some modules cannot even be simulated in the browser (e.g. `fs`). So "**any** Node module" is wrong.

Comment: Yes, true - some modules won't work in browser environment like in Node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Fortunately, i've said "I begin with vue.js" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Quentin, you cannot use a built in node backend library in your frontent code.

Use a library meant for browsers or a custom function like:

```js
const isRegExp1 = (value)=>{
  return {}.toString.call(value) === '[object RegExp]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) if you really need Node module. However in your example below code is sufficient:

```
const regEx = /test/;
if (regEx instanceof RegExp) {
    console.log('Success');
}
```